# js Model Animation Using three.js r68

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

As stated in the title, I cannot get animation to work. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in my code because it works [here](http://blacktowerentertainment.com/tools/animationviewer.html), but not [where I'm testing](http://e-shabazz.github.io/2DGame00/2DGame00.html).

I create the animation object in playerCharacter.js with

```
this.init = function(){
    for (var k in this.mesh.material.materials) {this.mesh.material.materials[k].skinning = true;}

    this.animation = new THREE.Animation(this.mesh, this.mesh.geometry.animations[0].name);
    this.animation.play();
}
```

In the update function I use:

```
    this.animation.update(0.017);
```

And when I look at the console log I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

So it seems that in THREE.AnimationHandler, data.hierarchy is undefined, so I'm guessing that if I can somehow make it defined, the problem will be fixed. Except I don't know how, or even why it is not defined. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing only the animation's name, not the whole `data` object. Use this instead:

```
this.animation = new THREE.Animation(this.mesh, this.mesh.geometry.animations[0]);
```

Comment: Well there are no more errors, so I guess you did answer my question :P But it is still not animating... why? Or should I make a new question for that?

Comment: I had the same problem, and this resolved the error message, but now the animation does not play for me either :(

Comment: it does not for me because `this.mesh.geometry.animations` is empty array, despite JSON file being 17MB long with entries like `"name": "animation_000002"`